# Find the same name in two tables

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

There are 2 tables, one table is the application and the other is an application filter which auto denies if it's too short, etc. I want to compare name in the both tables and if the name are exactly the same  then say "Automatically Denied".

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DY-XNQEMAIuG2hxHvzlbC1saCN3EKGuVTrLyuyutdk4/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In O429 I entered

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(E429:E), IF(ISTEXT(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(E429:E,'Applications Filter'!F:AF,1, 0))),"Automatically Denied","Waiting for an answer"),))
```

See if that works?